ServiceStack.Text latest version (8.3.0) nuget package issue within maui native iOS project
Issue - System.ArgumentException: Type MAUIiOSApp1.Service.UserRequest is not of type IList<> at ServiceStack.Text.Common.WriteLists`2[[MAUIiOSApp1.Service.UserRequest, MAUIiOSApp1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer, ServiceStack.Text, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].GetWriteFn() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/WriteLists.cs:line 495 at ServiceStack.Text.Common.WriteLists`2[[MAUIiOSApp1.Service.UserRequest, MAUIiOSApp1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer, ServiceStack.Text, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]..cctor() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/WriteLists.cs:line 481
using .net8.0 and it's working in simulator and this issue is only with real iOS device
tried lower versions as well and having same issue
issue while trying both get and post api
UserResponse response = await ServiceClient.PostAsync<UserResponse>(user);

Also same issue with serialize and deserialize as well
var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<UserRequest>(user);var obj = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<UserRequest>(json);


Did you try to debug to check the type of the UserRequest on real device?

yes  [Route("/create", "POST")]
public class UserRequest : IReturn
{
public string name { get; set; } .............

it's working now after adding true in property group of .csproj file

it's working now after adding UseInterpreter as true in property group of .csproj file
